# How can i define a datetime object in Python?

Tags: python, datetime

```
time1 = datetime.now();
time1 -= time1;
time2 = datetime.now();
time2 -= time2;
```

Thats how i try to define a datetime to be equal to Zero.
What is the right way to do it?

Thats what im trying to do:

```
import urllib2
from datetime import datetime

time1 = datetime.now();
time1 -= time1;
time2 = datetime.now();
time2 -= time2;
for i in range(0, 5):
    x = datetime.now()
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.google.com")
    time1 += datetime.now() - x
    x = datetime.now()
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://facebook.com") 
    time2 += datetime.now() - x
print time1
print time2
```

it works, but i believe it is wrong way to do so.

Comment: time1, time2 (after the "time1 -= time1" statement executed) is not datetime object. It's timedelta object. What you want is zero timedelta, you can make it with timedelta(0).

Comment: NameError: name 'timedelta' is not defined

Comment: timedelta is from datetime module. Import it first. (by "from datetime import datetime")

Comment: It's `datetime.timedelta`.

Comment: [`timedelta` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects).

Comment: Do you want to print elapsed time to fetch the webpage?

Comment: I m curious to know why you would need to do this..

Comment: im trying to compare the speed of 2 other webpges to see what page is better to obtain data from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the document says, the construction method is as following:

```
datetime(year, month, day[, hour[, minute[, second[, microsecond[,tzinfo]]]]])
```

And the `datetime.MINYEAR` is `1`, which means the minimum year value is `1`. So you can not define a `datetime` to be equal to `Zero`. With your method:

```
 time1 = datetime.now();
 time1 -= time1;
```

The object `time1` is changed to be `datetime.timedelta` not `datetime.datetime` object.

```
>>> time1 = datetime.datetime.now();
>>> time1
datetime.datetime(2013, 6, 9, 11, 13, 3, 57000)
>>> type(time1)
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> time1 -= time1;
>>> time1
datetime.timedelta(0)
>>> type(time1)
<class 'datetime.timedelta'>
```

Thanks to @falsetru, the method to define a timedelta as zero, we should do as:

```
zero = timedelta(0)
```

Comment: ok then, what is the right why to define datetime.timedelta that equals to Zero?

Comment: @Nirock, from datetime import timedelta; zero = timedelta(0)

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import urllib2

def benchmark(url, count=5):
    elapsed = timedelta(0)
    for i in range(count):
        time1 = datetime.now()
        u = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        try:
            u.read()
        finally:
            u.close()
        time2 = datetime.now()
        elapsed += time2 - time1
    return elapsed

for url in ("http://www.google.com", "http://facebook.com"):
    print url
    print benchmark(url)
```